# If I add a user to sudoers to be able to perform root functions

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, system, administrator

If I add a user to sudoers to be able to perform root functions, does it mean this user is the same as root?

Comment: What do you mean by "is the same as root"?

Comment: What actually is your question, please? I also tend to thinking that what you want to know can just be searched online and read about... If it's just for the knowledge sake, I think it must have been written somewhere sometime somehow. :) Btw, welcome to Ask Ubuntu @NatureSquare.

Answer (score 0):

No. It means that the user has the right to use the sudo command. Everything else he do on the system (without sudo) is done with his now mal privileges.

Answer (score 0):

No, Sudoers is controls who can run what commands as what `users` on what machines and can also control special things such as whether you need a password for particular commands.

You can give all command privileges to user, or just give some privileges to run particular command, like :

```
#allow all command to user with sudo
iamsudo  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

```
#only allow reboot command to user with sudo
iamsudo ALL=/usr/sbin/reboot
```

Hope this will help.